# OpenTSDB: Still hotspotting with random uids?

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

I'm bulk importing from archived sensor data to a 6 node OpenTSDB (2.4.0)/HBase (2.1.4) cluster and cannot figure out why essentially all of my writes are going to 1 region server.

I've created 40 metrics like `my_sensor.01`, `my_sensor.02`, ... `my_sensor.40` with `tsd.core.uid.random_metrics = true` in the config file; `tsdb uid grep ...` verifies that, yes, my metrics do have randomized uids.

I can also see using `tsdb scan ...` that my imported records are getting very different row ids like:

```
[41, 69 -37, 94, -3, 105, -48, 0, 0, 7, 0, -103, 84] my_sensor.01 1593666000 (Wed Jul 01 23:00:00 MDT 2020) {machine=139678208}
[101, -7, -109, 94, -3, 105, -48, 0, 0, 7, 0, -102, -87] my_sensor.02 1593666000 (Wed Jul 01 23:00:00 MDT 2020) {machine=144908352}
[85, 48, 7, 94, -3, 105, -48, 0, 0, 7, 0, -103, 78] my_sensor.03 1593666000 (Wed Jul 01 23:00:00 MDT 2020) {machine=143205834}
```

So why isn't this enough to cause my writes to be spread across different region servers?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There's a great deal of pre-existing data with row ids like [0, 0, ... ] so the new records are always coming after and being written to the last table region.